# Query to pull data between dates

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table that contains 2 date columns.  DATE1 and DATE2.
If I wanted to pull all records which have a DATE1 that is 6 months or greater than DATE2...how would I do that?

Pulling data from the same table..

Something like (pseudocode)

```
SELECT * FROM myTABLE
WHERE DATE1 IS 6 MONTHS OLDER THAN DATE2
```

Comment: where you want the data to be fetched from... other table or the same table?

Comment: @VishalWadhawan I've updated my question.  Pulling from the same table.  I want to get all records from MYTABLE where DATE1 is 6 months or older than DATE2

Comment: have you placed your pseudo code in Google? You'd be surprised as to what you'll find ;-)

Comment: `... where date1 - interval 6 month > date2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is that you would add or subtract a time period from the dates.

If by "6 months or greater" you mean "6 months or more", then here is an example:

```
where date1 <= date_sub(date2, interval 6 month)
```